# Override inline BODY width with PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP script that pulls HTML in as a string. Occasionally it pulls in code where the BODY tag has an inline width applied. If that width is 100%, it throws off some of the extra processing that occurs.

I don't think I can apply an external style because the inline one will likely supersede it. I'd also prefer to not have to use a DOM parser for something so small. Does anyone have a quick way that I can find and replace this?

Comment: If you're parsing the HTML with RegEx, **don't**. Use DOM instead.

Comment: He is not parsing it, he is replacing using RegEx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_replace("#<body(.*?)>#is", "<body>", $html, 1);
```

...

```
$html = "<body style='width:800px;'></body>";
echo preg_replace("#<body(.*?)>#is", "<body>", $html, 1);
```

...

```
<body></body>
```

Comment: This is perfect! I have no clue how it works though. Thank you!

Comment: `(.*?)` means match any character 0 or more times, ungreedy. `is` means case insensitive with whitespace. `(.*?)` is everything between `<body` and `>`. `1` means replace just 1, but there is 1 `body` tag anyway. These are regular expressions, a must :)

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! My regular expression experience has been limited to alpha numerics, trying to grasp some of this more advanced stuff.

Comment: Print this http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/ and keep it on your table until you no longer need it :)

Comment: I've already got a Sitepoint one taped under my glass desktop!